# How can I send many variables to controller in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I can send one instance to my controller use resource attribute in form:

```
<g:form url="[resource:appealInstance, action:'save']">
......  
<g:submitButton name="create"/>
</g:form>
```

and

```
def save(Appeal appealInstance) {
}
```

but how can i send many instances? I tried to do something like

```
<g:form url="[resource:[appealInstance, documentInstance], action:'save']">
```

and

```
 def save(Appeal appealInstance, Document documentInstance) {
 }
```

but it does not works

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use hidden form parameters?

```
<input type="hidden" name="appealInstance.id" value="${appealInstance.id}" />
<input type="hidden" name="documentInstance.id" value="${documentInstance.id}" />
```

afaik, this should do the trick. The params array should also be a good location for the reference to your objects (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/form.html)

The http request never sends the whole object, only a reference or the contents of properties. You can read more about the Grails data binding in the documentation: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding